# Vuejs + Cornerstonejs - Render a stack of images

Tags: vue.js, cornerstone, cornerstonejs

I'm having difficulties implementing the rendering of several DICOM files in cornerstonejs. The documentation shows some examples but nothing that helps much, since they are using images from an external system. Can anyone help me render multiple DICOM files in the cornerstonejs viewport?